# Is nested Table an efficient way to generate nested list?

Tags: list-manipulation

If I want to have a nested list like 10 times of `{1,2..,9,10}`:

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1,
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2,
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}
```

I can easily understand that `Table[i,{i,1,10}]` will give me a sub list `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`, so I can imagine if I want to have ten same sub lists I need to apply this table function for ten times, so I use `Table[Table[i,{i,1,10}],{10}]` to get what I want.

But I know for the language of Mathematica, things could happen a lot of miraculous than I thought, there must be some more elegant ways to manipulate lists. My question is asking do you think 'Table[Table[expr, ],{conditions}]' stuff are good implementations in terms of efficiency in my case?

Comment: `Table` is likely pretty efficient, barring the lists having special structure (like the example you showed). However, you don't need to nest `Table`s: You can just do `Table[i, {10}, {i, 1, 10}]`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for telling me this method!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Extract** is much faster than all alternatives posted/mentioned so far.

```
Extract[{Range @ 5}, ConstantArray[{1}, 5]] // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

**Timings:** Using @BobHanlon's timing setup:

```
n = 10^3;
{t1 = AbsoluteTiming[tab1 = Table[i, {n}, {i, 1, n}];][[1]], 
 t2 = AbsoluteTiming[tab2 = Table[Range[n], {n}];][[1]], 
 t3 = AbsoluteTiming[tab3 = Table[Table[i, {i, 1, n}], {n}];][[1]], 
 t4 = AbsoluteTiming[tab4 = ConstantArray[Range[n], n];][[1]],
 t5 = AbsoluteTiming[tab5 = Extract[{Range[n]}, ConstantArray[{1}, n]];][[1]]}
```

> {5.844533, 0.104275, 0.750996, 0.095255, 0.001003}

```
% / t5 // Round[#, 1]&
```

> {5825, 104, 748, 95, 1}

```
 tab1 == tab2 == tab3 == tab4 == tab5
```

> True

For `n = 10^4;` we get

```
{t1, t2, t3, t4, t5}
```

> {24.885165, 1.786752, 2.813479, 0.323860, 0.001003}

```
% / t5 // Round[#, 1]&
```

> {24801, 1781, 2804, 323, 1}

**Update:** **Part** + **ConstantArray**

```
{Range[5]}[[ConstantArray[1, 5]]] // TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccc}
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
>  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

This is as fast or faster than `Extract`:

```
n = 10^4;
{t5 = AbsoluteTiming[tab5 = Extract[{Range[n]}, ConstantArray[{1}, n]];][[1]],
 t6 = AbsoluteTiming[tab6 = {Range[n]}[[ConstantArray[1, n]]];][[1]]}
```

> {0.003003, 0.001006}

```
tab5 == tab6
```

> True

Comment: Very nice comparison!

Comment: Wow, I am quite surprised that `ConstantArray[Range[n], n]` performs so badly.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher,  I wasn't expecting this either.

Answer (score 7):

The list can be constructed by more specific functions than `Table`:

```
ConstantArray[Range[10], 10]

(*{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1,
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2,
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}*)
```

Comment: Time comparison with `n=10^4`: `Table[Table[i, {i, 1, n}], {n}]; // RepeatedTiming` gave `0.84`, and `ConstantArray[Range[n], n]; // RepeatedTiming` gave `0.076`.

Answer (score 3):

The relative timings can change significantly with `n`

```
n = 10^2;

{t1 = RepeatedTiming[tab1 = Table[i, {n}, {i, 1, n}];][[1]],
 t2 = RepeatedTiming[tab2 = Table[Range[n], {n}];][[1]],
 t3 = RepeatedTiming[tab3 = Table[Table[i, {i, 1, n}], {n}];][[1]], 
 t4 = RepeatedTiming[tab4 = ConstantArray[Range[n], n];][[1]]}

(* {0.00069, 0.00008, 0.00069, 4.*10^-6} *)

%/t4 // N

(* {180.947, 19.9453, 182.789, 1.} *)
```

Note that the `nested tables` is the slowest.

Verifying that all four approaches give the same result

```
tab1 === tab2 === tab3 === tab4

(* True *)
```

Increasing `n`

```
n = 10^3;

{t1 = RepeatedTiming[tab1 = Table[i, {n}, {i, 1, n}];][[1]],
 t2 = RepeatedTiming[tab2 = Table[Range[n], {n}];][[1]],
 t3 = RepeatedTiming[tab3 = Table[Table[i, {i, 1, n}], {n}];][[1]], 
 t4 = RepeatedTiming[tab4 = ConstantArray[Range[n], n];][[1]]}

(* {0.064, 0.010, 0.0099, 0.00075} *)

%/t4 // N

(* {85.5733, 13.388, 13.181, 1.} *)
```

Note that the `nested tables` is no longer the slowest.

```
tab1 === tab2 === tab3 === tab4

(* True *)
```

Further increasing `n`

```
n = 10^4;

{t1 = RepeatedTiming[tab1 = Table[i, {n}, {i, 1, n}];][[1]],
 t2 = RepeatedTiming[tab2 = Table[Range[n], {n}];][[1]],
 t3 = RepeatedTiming[tab3 = Table[Table[i, {i, 1, n}], {n}];][[1]], 
 t4 = RepeatedTiming[tab4 = ConstantArray[Range[n], n];][[1]]}

(* {10.3, 1.8, 0.93, 0.51} *)

%/t4 // N

(* {20.1379, 3.51058, 1.83164, 1.} *)

tab1 === tab2 === tab3 === tab4

(* True *)
```