# How can I get a recursion `f[f[f[x],x],x]` n times with minimal amount of code

Tags: list-manipulation, recursion

`Nest[f,x,3] = f[f[f[x]]]` But I want something like `Fn[f,x,3] = f[f[f[x],x],x]`. I think there exist some function to do that. Actually I need to copy a list $n$ times and Join with itself. So I will use

```
lst = {a,b,c}
Fn[Join, lst, 3] = Join[Join[Join[lst], lst], lst] = {a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c}
```

I assume something like this `Fn` already exist in Mathematica. But I am not sure. Is there any other way to simply duplicate a list and concatenate with itself $n$ times ?

Comment: closely realted: [Is nested Table an efficient way to generate nested list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/163122/125)

Comment: Join @@ (lst & /@ (Range[3]^0))

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/346882).

Comment: Well I placed both X and Y. :-)

Comment: `PadRight[{}, 9, {a, b, c}]` works, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Nest[f[#, x] &, f[x], 2]
```

Redefine the function you're nesting slightly so that it includes the extension.

Alternatively, to solve the problem you're asking for (concatenating a list to itself several times), `Flatten` the first layer of a `ConstantArray`:

```
Flatten[ConstantArray[list, 3], 1]
```

Comment: Thanks `Join` can also be used in place of `Flatten[ , 1]`. One extra argument. I was missing the `ConstantArray` function

Answer (score 9):

```
Fold[f, ConstantArray[x, 3 + 1]]
```

For duplicating lists, usually the following is surprisingly fast:

```
Flatten[{lst}[[ConstantArray[1, 3]]]]
```

Answer (score 8):

> Is there any other way to simply duplicate a list and concatenate with itself n times ?

Many ways. Here are two:

```
Flatten[Table[lst, 3]]
Join @@ Table[lst, 3]
```

Comment: I think second one is better. if the `lst` is a matrix then it works. However for the first one an extra argument `1` is required.